# How to grep JSON on change of select box with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, onchange, faceted-search

I'm still a bit of a newbie when it comes to finding data and displaying it from a JSON object, so take my questions for what it's worth and I'll try to be as detailed as possible.

I need a bit of help writing some jQuery that will take the value of an option in a select box on the change event and filter a list that is populated from a JSON object.

Basically what I'm trying to get to eventually, is a multi dimensional faceted navigational model that takes a JSON object and allows a user to filter that list on the change event.

I realize this is a bit vague, but I'll try and answer you're questions as much as possible.

Here's what I have so far for JS:

```
function getBeers(){
    $.grep(getBeerType, function(key, val){
      $.getJSON('includes/data.json', function(data) {
        var beers = [];

        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
          beers.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
        });

        $('<ul/>', {
          html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('#beerlist');
      });
    });
  };

  $("#beerselector").change(function(){
    var getBeerType = $(this).val();
    getBeers(getBeerType);
  });
```

and JSON:

```
{"beers":[
        {
            "name":"Surly Wet",
            "type":"Ale"
        },
        {
            "name":"Spaten Oktoberfest",
            "type":"Lager"
        },
        {
            "name":"Pliny the Elder",
            "type":"Ale"
        },
        {
            "name":"Summit IPA",
            "type":"Ale"
        },
        {
            "name":"Surly Coffee Bender",
            "type":"Porter"
        },
        {
            "name":"Lagunitas IPA",
            "type":"Ale"
        }
]}
```

and HTML:

```
  <label for="beerselector">What's your favorite beer type?</label>
  <select id="beerselector">
    <option value="">I like all beer</option>
    <option value="ale">Ales</option>
    <option value="lager">Lagers</option>
  </select>

  <div id="beerlist"></div>
```

Comment: How about showing some code with what you have done so far?

Comment: The problem is that you're basically asking us to write this code for you from scratch. You need to at least give it a shot, with some code examples, and then ask for help on something specific. We're here to help, but not to do all the work for you :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.

Comment: $.grep expects an array to be passed as the first argument, you're passing a string value. Your `$.each` function is iterating over just the first tier of the array, which is actually `beers : [{}]`, where as you should be doing `$.each(data.beers`. The `$.grep` should also be inside of the `success` from the `$.getJSON` request.